# I want to store each group in the below output into separate vectors or arrays. If not any other way to store the each group individually

Tags: c++, c++11

I have tried code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
std::vector< std::vector<T> > split(std::vector<T> vec, uint64_t n) {
std::vector< std::vector<T> > vec_of_vecs(n);

uint64_t quotient = vec.size() / n;
uint64_t reminder = vec.size() % n;
uint64_t first = 0;
uint64_t last;
for (uint64_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
if (i < reminder) {
last = first + quotient + 1;
vec_of_vecs[i] = std::vector<T>(vec.begin() + first, vec.begin() + last);
first = last;
}
else if (i != n - 1) {
last = first +  quotient;
vec_of_vecs[i] = std::vector<T>(vec.begin() + first, vec.begin() + last);
first = last;
}
else
vec_of_vecs[i] = std::vector<T>(vec.begin() + first, vec.end());
}

return vec_of_vecs;
}

#define Nsta 30
#define NGroups 5

int main(void)
{
std::vector<uint64_t> vector(Nsta);
std::iota(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector), 1);

std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> vecs(NGroups);
vecs = split(vector, NGroups);

for (uint64_t m = 0; m < vecs.size(); ++m) 
{
for (auto i : vecs[m])
{
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << i << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
}
 return 0;
}
```

**Output of this code:**

1 2 3 4 5 6
 7 8 9 10 11 12
 13 14 15 16 17 18
 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30

**What i want is:**

This is only small part  in my work. I would like to use each group based on work conditions.

**please help with this!**

Comment: The complete lack of logical indentation results in the shown code being mostly unreadable. People who might want to help you with your problem may not be even able to read the code, as shown. If you would like some help with your problem you should make it as easy as possible for everyone else to read your question, and understand it.

Comment: "I want each of the group to store in separate array." - What are you trying to achieve? You can write the desired output as well. The question has no information whatsoever, on what transformation is required in the final result.

Comment: i am going use only one element from one group at a time for my simulation. if they store in separate arrays, it makes my job easy. i can call an element from each array based on simulation flow.  Suppose lets say Group 1...Groupn are subarrays. i want about output(each split group) to be stored in different subarrays.

Comment: or Is it possible to store above output in one array or vector?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop body does something else. Bellow is the code that follows your requirements.

```
template<typename T>
std::vector< std::vector<T> > split(std::vector<T> vec, size_t n) {
  std::vector< std::vector<T> > vec_of_vecs(n);

  size_t quotient = vec.size() / n;
  size_t reminder = vec.size() % n;
  size_t first = 0;
  size_t last = quotient;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i, first += quotient, last += quotient) {
    vec_of_vecs.push_back(std::vector<T>(&vec[first], &vec[last]));
  }
  if (reminder > 0) {
    vec_of_vecs.push_back(std::vector<T>(vec.begin() + first, vec.end()));
  }
}
```

Comment: if the code above is not satisfying my question then please suggest me the other way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But i want store each group in separate array with different names. can you please suggest something related to this part.

Comment: Can you provide example, what you want to get? C++ can not create arrays with different names. Maybe you need some map collection.

Comment: i am going use only one element from one group at a time for my simulation. if they store in separate arrays, it makes my job easy. i can call an element from each array based on simulation flow. Suppose lets say Group 1...Groupn are subarrays. i want about output(each split group) to be stored in different subarrays. please suggest if there anyway to handle my problem.